# problem of visiting some sites with Cypress, if the same sites can be seen without problems in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cypress, puppeteer

I'm trying to log into my Facebook account with Cypress, but I can't:

```
describe("Facebook Login", () => {
    it('facebook', () => {
        cy.visit('https://www.facebook.com/');
    })
})
```

[image: cypress facebook]

i test this options on config:

```
"experimentalSessionAndOrigin": true,
"experimentalModifyObstructiveThirdPartyCode": true,
"watchForFileChanges": false,
"chromeWebSecurity": false
```

What is different in Cypress, from an actual browser? When I open a new browser tab in Cypress and go to Facebook.com, I can manually log in fine.

I tested Selenium and it worked fine.

Comment: @Kiowa No, error on facebook login.